# docker won't show stats, says 'command not found'

Tags: docker, metrics

I am very confused about how the docker stats command is supposed to run, mostly because for me, it won't. According to their docs I should be able to execute `dockers stats <id>` and get information but I am only getting `Error: Command not found: stats`.

I can not find a single similar issue and am very confused as to why it would happen. For all intents and purposes this should work. When I run the command and docker gives the typical list of recommendations on the CLI, stats isn't even listed.

Is there any reason this command should fail? Is there some other package I need to install to make this comman run?

Comment: What version of docker are you running?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `stats` API endpoint (and corresponding CLI command) was added in [Docker v1.5](http://blog.docker.com/2015/02/docker-1-5-ipv6-support-read-only-containers-stats-named-dockerfiles-and-more/). If that command is not listed as an option, you're likely running an older version, and will need to upgrade.

Comment: yup. thats it. for some reason the docker site says to install in such a way that you get an older version. fixed thank you.